# How can I redirect to a html file inside a exception?

Tags: spring-boot, exception

I have a method that can execute a Exception, I dont now how to redirect to a web page inside templates. If it happen the exception

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class NoCordInRouteFoundException extends RuntimeException {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using annotations directly on top of the exception, you can define an exception handler by using the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation:

```java
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@ExceptionHandler(NoCordInRouteFoundException.class)
public String noCordInRouteFound(NoCordInRouteFoundException ex) {
    return "template";
}
```

Add this method to a specific controller to be able to use a specific template when an exception is thrown in any of the other methods within the controller, or add the method within a separate class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` so that it will be applied for all controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the help ;D